# Add a new row in the free jqgrid not showing

Tags: jquery, free-jqgrid

I want to add a row to my grid, which uses the free version of jqgrid.
Because the build in add button is not very intuitive, I am using a separate add button.
So I want to do something like this;

```
$("#btnAddContract").click(function () {
    var id = $("#ContractId").val();
    var url = GetHiddenField("sir-selected-contract-url") + id + "/add";
    var callback = contractAdded;
    dataService.addSelectedContract(url, callback);
});

var contractAdded = function (data) {
    var grid = $("#grid");
    var position = 0;
    grid.insertRow(data, position); // pseudo code - this cannot work
}
```

Of course the grid.insertRow method does not exist. What should I be using to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid has the method `addRowData`, which allows to add new row to the grid. You don't posted the JavaScript code, which you use to *create* jqGrid. Thus I have to guess some things.

First of all, if you use local grid (`datatype: "local"`), then adding the row is pure *local* changing of jqGrid without any communication with the server. The method `addRowData` is low-level method. It allows to add new row *without* forcing sorting of data and without testing the current size of the page. As the result you can add the row before/after any other row of the grid. After adding the row, the number of rows could be larger as the page size.

It's important to know that **every row of the grid has `id` attribute** (the rowid). See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div). The `id` value of new row is the first parameter of `addRowData`. The second parameter of `addRowData` is the object with the data of the row. The third parameter specifies the position of the new row in the grid. It could be: `"first"`, `"last"`, `"before"`, `"after"`, `"afterSelected"`, `"beforeSelected"`. The 4-th parameter of `addRowData` should be specified only if you use `"before"` or `"after"` as the 3-d parameter. It specifies the rowid of the row, before/after which the new row should be added.

One more possibility to add new row to the grid would be the following code:

```js
var p = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to all parameters
p.data = newData; // replace the data array to another data
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid", { current: true }); // reload holding the selection
```

One can see that the above code can be used to **replace** the data of the grid with another data. It could take a little more time as the call of `addRowData`, but the large advantage of the approach: you will see correctly sorted data. The page size and the information in the pager will be absolutely correct too. I recommend you to test both ways and to see which one better corresponds your requirements.